# Abstracting Push Notification In Java

Tags: java, frameworks, messaging

My question is : Is there any Push Notification abstraction layer/Framework for Java that separate the interface with the implementation providers (Android and iOS)?

The details are below:

Here is my use case:

1. User initiates a task through their mobile phones (currently targeting Android and iOS)
2. This task would run asynchronously on the server (J2EE based application server)
3. Once the task is done, I would like the server to notify the completion of the task via Push Notification to the user

Now I understand, we could do that through C2DM and there are code to integrate APN via Java from project such as [Java APN](http://code.google.com/p/javapns/).

I am basically looking for abstraction layer for Push Notification that abstracts out the interface and provider/implementation layer similar to what JDBC does with the databases and JMS with messaging.

To reiterate the question: Is there a Java Framework that standardize Push Notification across devices (Android and iOS at least), provide a logical interface and abstract out the implementation layer from me?

If such Java Framework doesn't exists then I will have to create one, but I thought I asked before taking the task myself.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[Urban Airship](http://urbanairship.com/) is a service (not a framework), but it might help you abstract away some of the push notification infrastructure you'd need to write otherwise.

Comment: thanks! Let me look into the sample code and see if it is enough for what I am trying to do.

Comment: Looks like until standardize framework comes up to abstract concept of push notification, I will have to use Urban Airship :) Thanks for the answer